# UIStoryboard open from another UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have a problem with calling one UIStoryboard from the second. My first Storyboard - Main, second - Management. When you click UIButton no action occurs. My source code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Management" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController *yourViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Management"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a segue?

Comment: Maybe not use. You can show me how it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need replace old code by this.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Management" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                                            UIViewController *yourViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ManagementIDS"];
                                            [self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons may be here.
1. You might forgot to setup IBAction outlet to your UIButton 
2. Storyboard names may not match you specify in your code
3. [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Management"]; are you sure you specified the same Storyboard ID for this controller?
4. In order to check all these suggestions it's enough just to set breakpoint on first line of your code and try to reproduce the situation.

Comment: I try now use another instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

Many wrong things can happen in that code.

First of all be sure that your action is well connected, put a breakpoint in your action to see if that is being called.

Second be sure that the storyboard name is correct, put a breakpoint after storyboard and check if it isn't nil (`po storyboard` in the debug console).

Second be sure that the "Management.storyboard" has a ViewController with the identifier "Management". So put a breakpoint after yourViewController to check if it is nil (`po yourViewController` in the debugger console).

Finally be sure that the view controller where you have the action is inside the navigation controller. So check if self.navigationController is nil (`po self.navigationController` in the debugger console after you stopped in the action's code)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer doing it in interface builder than in code:

You can now create a storyboard reference in interface builder. That means you can link a storyboard from another storyboard. Target must be ios9.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014225-CH49-SW1

check 19:00
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=407